# Create rails record from two ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The functionality I'm trying to build allows Users to Visit a Restaurant.

I have Users, Locations, and Restaurants models.
Locations have many Restaurants.

I've created a Visits model with user_id and restaurant_id attributes, and a visits_controller with create and destroy methods.

Thing is, I **can't create an actual Visit record**. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this? Or am I going about it the wrong way.

## Routing Error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"restaurants", :location_id=>nil}
```

## Code:

Routes:

```
location_restaurant_visits POST   /locations/:location_id/restaurants/:restaurant_id/visits(.:format)     visits#create
 location_restaurant_visit DELETE /locations/:location_id/restaurants/:restaurant_id/visits/:id(.:format) visits#destroy
```

Model:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :restaurant_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

View:

```
  <% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
    <%= link_to 'Visit', location_restaurant_visits_path(current_user.id, restaurant.id), method: :create %>
    <% @visit = Visit.find_by_user_id_and_restaurant_id(current_user.id, restaurant.id) %>
    <%= @visit != nil ? "true" : "false" %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_restaurant
  before_filter :find_user

  def create

    @visit = Visit.create(params[:user_id => @user.id, :restaurant_id => @restaurant.id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @visit.save
        format.html { redirect_to location_restaurants_path(@location), notice: 'Visit created.' }
        format.json { render json: @visit, status: :created, location: @visit }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @visit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @visit = Visit.find(params[:user_id => @user.id, :restaurant_id => @restaurant.id])
    @restaurant.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to location_restaurants_path(@restaurant.location_id), notice: 'Unvisited.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def find_restaurant
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
  end

  def find_user
    @user = current_user
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of problems here. The first is this line of code in your `VisitController`'s `create` action (and identical line in your `destroy` action):

```
@visit = Visit.create(params[:user_id => @user.id, :restaurant_id => @restaurant.id])
```

`params` is a [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), so you should be passing it a key (if anything), not a bunch of `key => value` bindings. What you probably meant was:

```
@visit = Visit.create(:user_id => @user.id, :restaurant_id => @restaurant.id)
```

Note that you initialize `@user` and `@restaurant` in before filter methods, so you don't need to access `params` here.

This line of code is still a bit strange, though, because you are creating a record and then a few lines later you are saving it (`if @visit.save`). This is redundant: `Visit.create` initiates and saves the record, so saving it afterwards is pretty much meaningless. What you probably want to do is first initiate a new `Visit` with `Visit.new`, then save that:

```
def create

  @visit = Visit.new(:user_id => @user.id, :restaurant_id => @restaurant.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @visit.save
    ...
```

The next thing I notice is that you have not initiated a `@location` in your `create` action, but you then reference it here:

```
format.html { redirect_to location_restaurants_path(@location), notice: 'Visit created.' }
```

Since you will need the location for every restaurant route (since `restaurant` is a nested resource), you might as well create a method and `before_filter` for it, like you have with `find_restaurant`:

```
before_filter :find_location

...

def find_location
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
end
```

The next problem is that in your view your `location_restaurant_path` is passed the `id` of `current_user` and of `restaurant`. There are two problems here. First of all the first argument should be a location, not a user (matching the order in `location_restaurant_path`). The next  problem is that for the `_path` methods, you have to pass the actual object, not the object's id. Finally, you have `method: :create`, but the `method` here is referring to the HTTP method, so what you want is `method: :post`:

```
link_to 'Visit', location_restaurant_visits_path(@location, restaurant.id), method: :post
```

You'll have to add a `find_location` before filter to your `RestaurantController` to make `@location` available in the view here.

There may be other problems, but these are some things to start with.

Comment: Perfect, thanks especially for clarifying the params/hash bit.

Answer (score 0):

`location_id` is `nil` and the path definition doesn't say `(/:location_id)` forcing a non-nil value there in order to route to that path; create a new route without `location_id` if you can derive it from a child's attribute (i.e. a `restaurant_id` refers to a `Restaurant` which already knows its own `location_id`).